# Error when using dplyr case_when based on two variables

Tags: r

Seeing a new error in an old, previously functioning R Markdown document with `case_when` I'm not able to interpret.  I did a global package update recently, and wonder if something was affected.

I can use two sequential `case_when` operation (one for the "what" condition, an other for the "how" condition), but the second overwrites the first, using the `TRUE` last option also causes an error, and [case_when](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) documentation seems to show that creating a case based on multiple variables is allowable.

```r
case_character_type <- function(height, mass, species) {
  case_when(
    height > 200 | mass > 200 ~ "large",
    species == "Droid"        ~ "robot",
    TRUE                      ~ "other"
  )
}

case_character_type(150, 250, "Droid")
#> [1] "large"
case_character_type(150, 150, "Droid")
#> [1] "robot"
```

Thanks in advance.

Reprex:

```r
texp <- structure(list(exercise_tf = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                                       TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
                       how = c("walk", "bike", "bike", 
                               "drive", "walk", "bike", "bike", "drive_train", "drive", "drive_train"), 
                       time_commute_min = c(10, 25, 30, 15, 10, 25, 30, 26, 20, 26), 
                       what = c("to bjj", "to work", "home from work", "to f3", "to bjj", 
                                "to work", "home from work", "to bjj", "to f3", "to bjj")), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 
                                -10L), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
# Works OK in isolation
texp %>%
  mutate(ex_time =
           case_when(grepl("bike", how) ~ time_commute_min))

# Works OK in isolation
texp %>% 
  mutate(ex_time = 
           case_when(grepl("to bjj", what) ~ 45L,
                     grepl("to f3", what) ~ 45L))

# Error
texp %>%
  filter(exercise_tf) %>% 
  mutate(ex_time =
           case_when(
             grepl("bike", how) ~ time_commute_min,
             grepl("to bjj", what) ~ 45L,
             grepl("to f3", what) ~ 45L
           )
  )

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `ex_time = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:

Backtrace:
 1. texp %>% filter(exercise_tf) %>% ...
 7. dplyr::case_when(...)
 Error in mutate(., ex_time = case_when(grepl("bike", how) ~ time_commute_min, : 

Caused by error in `case_when()`:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: this seems related to mixed outputs, not mixed inputs.

I realized I was trying to enforce integer type on a numeric column, found in `check_type` in the `last_trace`, but was not terribly helpful pinning it down.

```r
...
  7. └─dplyr::case_when(...)
  8.   └─dplyr:::replace_with(...)
  9.     └─dplyr:::check_type(val, x, name, error_call = error_call)
 10.       └─rlang::abort(msg, call = error_call)

# works as expected
texp %>%
  mutate(ex_time =
           case_when(grepl("bike", how) ~ time_commute_min,
                     grepl("to bjj", what) ~ 45,
                     grepl("to f3", what) ~ 45))
```